# How to only show a subset of data in a table by using alter and select in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
TagName, DateTime, Value
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0013.PV_Top_Temp', '2022-07-05 11:27:43.7810000', '86.4'
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0013.PV_Bot_Temp', '2022-07-05 11:27:43.7030000', '25.1'
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0065.PV_HUMIDITY', '2022-07-05 11:27:43.6890000', '85.11'
'SG_QRA_SGHAST_0066.PV_HUMIDITY', '2022-07-05 11:27:43.6890000', '38.48'
```

What I want to do is to to alter the table to only show this permanently but i am unable to do so now:

```
TagName, DateTime, Value
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0013.PV_Top_Temp', '2022-07-05 11:27:43.7810000', '86.4'
'SG_QRA_SGTC_0013.PV_Bot_Temp', '2022-07-05 11:27:43.7030000', '25.1'
```

with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM testingintern WHERE TagName like '%Top%' OR TagName like '%Bot% AND TIME(DateTime) = '11:27:43';
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the query you posted, the problem I see with it is that you forgot a ' after `'%bot%`, so it thinks you want something that contains `%Bot% AND TIME(DateTime) = '11:27:43'` instead of just `%bot%`. Making it `'%bot%'` should fix or at least get you going in the right direction

Comment: in the future, try to include what happened when you ran your query. Did it give you an error? if so what error and possibly highlight where in your query is being deemed an error? or you didnt get any errors, but it didnt produce the results you wanted. It gives people a lot more information to work from :)